# SELECT hangs when using a variable

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014 (v13.0.4001.0) - this sample script hangs:

```
DECLARE @from int = 0
DECLARE @to int = 1000

select  
    *
from 
    TaskNote dtn 
join 
    Participants tp on dtn.Task_ID = tp.TaskId
where 
    dtn.TaskNote_ID between @from and @to
```

But if I change variables to constants - it is all OK.

Like this:

```
where 
    dtn.DocTaskNote_ID between 0 and 1000
```

Also, if I remove the join, all is ok.

Can't figure out where the problem is

Comment: Optimized differently?

Comment: Typically when a query hangs you'll want to check the execution plan. Likely you are no longer using and index that you were before or alternatively an index on the table is being re-built because of you running the query. Just some things to check!

Comment: script with variable and with constants got different estimated execution plans. But cant compare actual execution plans becouse script hangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible cause for the problem you mention, in case your query lies within a stored procedure, is parameter sniffing. SQL Server compiles the query for the first time using the initial values of the parameters. In subsequent calls to the procedure the engine uses the cached execution plan which is probably not optimal for the current variable values.

One workaround this problem is to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`:

```
select *
from TaskNote dtn 
join Participants tp on dtn.Task_ID = tp.TaskId
where dtn.TaskNote_ID between @from and @to
option (recompile)
```

This way the query is being compiled every time the procedure is executed using the current parameters values.

Further reading:

- [**Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)

Comment: if i put script with tnis option into while loop, could it be some performance decrease?

Comment: @aleha You should first consider converting the while loop to a set based solution.